# Symbolicate crash in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I dragged the crash logs into the organizer and I also have the IPA file as well as the dSYM file. However, if I press Resymbolicate in the organizer, nothing happens.

I also tried to run symbolicatecrash via terminal by doing:

`sh symbolicatecrash /Users/username/Desktop/a.crash /Users/username/Desktop/a.dSYM`

but I get:

`symbolicatecrash: line 14: use: command not found
symbolicatecrash: line 15: use: command not found
symbolicatecrash: line 16: use: command not found
symbolicatecrash: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token ('
symbolicatecrash: line 17: use Cwd qw(realpath);'`

I renamed the crash and dSYM file to a to make typing it easier.

Answer (score 2):

For xcode 6 you can find the symbolicatecrash file in this location  `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Ver‌​sions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash` Just copy the file store it on your desktop folder after that run this command Now go to the folder from your terminal export developer directory with this `export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer"` and run this command `./symbolicatecrash -A -v CrashFile.crash  YourApp.app.dSYM`

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking `symbolicatecrash` in a weird way. It’s a Perl script, not a shell script, and it’s already executable, so you should be able just to do

```
symbolicatecrash /Users/username/Desktop/a.crash /Users/username/Desktop/a.dSYM
```

Comment: When I do that, I get: -bash: symbolicatecrash: command not found

Comment: In that case, use the full path, e.g. `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash`.

Comment: Well, where is the `symbolicatecrash` that you were invoking in your original question? Just use that file. My point is that you should be calling it directly, not passing it to `bash`.

Comment: I downloaded that from the internet on a tutorial for symbolicatecrash. The website had a link to download it in case you could not find it on your computer. Anyway, when I try to run it, it gives me: `-bash: symbolicatecrash: command not found`

Comment: In that case you need to run `chmod u+x symbolicatecrash`, `mv symbolicatecrash /usr/local/bin`, and `hash -r` so that bash can see it. Of course, be wary of code you downloaded from some site on the internet…

Comment: Ok, so now I got the script running, but the output file is still just memory addresses. No symbols.

Comment: @codenamepenryn You should open a new question with this new problem.